# delete species names and arrows from ggord NMDS plot

Tags: r, mds

I used ggord to create NMDS plot in R. It shows both plots and species together, but I want to remove all species names and arrows as well from the plot. Any solution?

Here is my code:

```
ggord(spherblr.nmds, envherblr$ecoutil, 
      cols=c("red", "lightcoral", "chocolate", "orange", "darkgreen", "yellowgreen"))+
  scale_shape_manual("Groups", values=c(15, 0, 19, 1, 17, 2))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  geom_text(mapping = NULL, label="none")
```

My plot looks as follows: [image: NMDS plot]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `txt = NULL` to `ggord` to suppress text labels, and `veclsz = 0` to suppress the arrows:

```
ord = prcomp(iris[, 1:4])
ggord(ord, iris$Species, txt = NULL, veclsz = 0)
```

[image: PCA of iris]

Comment: After this arrows stay still there.

Answer (score 1):

So in my case worked the following `ggord(ord, iris$Species, txt = NULL, vectyp=0)`